# Toggling between true and false

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  hello: true ,

  actions:{
    switch: function(hello){
      if (hello === false) {
        this.set(hello, true);
      } else if (hello === true) {
        this.set(hello, false);
      }  
    }
  }
});
```

> I'm trying to toggle between the false and true options however this always returns false. I need it so that it switches between the two depending on the its current value. I have a button which runs this function. Initially i want it to change from true to false then if its clicked again to change to true etc...

Comment: your condition should be `===` or `==` not `=`

Comment: yeah, i just changed it to that and it still doesn't work, it always returns false

Comment: do you want to set `hello`  to the value you pass to the `switch` function or just toggle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is ok, but the mistake is that you are not actually setting the `hello` attribute. As written, your code would show an error in the console that would give some clues. Corrected code below, note the quotation marks around `'hello'`:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  hello: true ,

  actions:{
    switch: function(hello){
      if (hello === false){
        this.set('hello', true);
      } else if (hello === true){
        this.set('hello', false);
      }  
   }
})
```

In your original code snippet, the value of the `hello` argument of your action is "true". Therefore your code was saying, `this.set(true, false)`. The `this.set` method expects to receive the name of a variable as a string and its value.

Also, Ember components have a method called [toggleProperty](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.4/classes/Component/methods/toggleProperty?anchor=toggleProperty) that is helpful here:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  hello: true ,

  actions:{
      switch() {
        this.toggleProperty('hello')
      }
    }
});
```

Some of the other answers to this question do not (yet) account for the need to use `this.set`, which is an Ember-specific requirement for observability of variables.

This answer applies from Ember 1.13 through at least 3.x. For versions of Ember less than 3, the `import` and `export` lines change, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't really want a parameter for your switch function, but just always toggle the `hello` property. If yes then do this:

```
switch() { // here no parameter
  this.set('hello', !this.hello); // dont forget the '' for `this.set`.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, conditions use `===`, `!==`, `==`, etc.

Second, `this.set('hello', !hello)` requires no If conditions, or anything else.

Explanation:

`!` is conditional operator.
It checks if condition is false, null or undefined.

But you can use it for switching between true and false.

Comment: This works for changing it initially however, when the button is pressed again it remains false still...

Comment: @J.Fair You are doing something wrong. I tested it and it works for me fine. If it doesn't work for you, doesn't mean it is bad and you have to thumbs down it.

Comment: i wasn't the one who  did the thumbs down mate, i'm not able to do thumbs down or up and my reputation is too low..

Comment: Added a thumbs up to cancel it out. Looks like working code to me

Answer (score -1):

you could try this:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  hello: true ,

  actions:{
      switch: (hello) => {
        this.set('hello', (hello ^= 1) == true)
      }
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  hello: true ,

  actions:{
      switch: (hello) => this.set('hello', !hello)
    }
});
```

Comment: Use the latter; the first is entirely too "clever" for use in production code.

Comment: This is why I gave two answers, the first could be utilised when the original value may not be a boolean and is instead a number or string.

Comment: This example is on the right track, but it's required to use `this.set` in Ember for changing the value of a property on a Component object. I have submitted an edit. `this.set` enables other parts of the application to respond to the change in value.

Comment: `this` in your answers will always be undefined, you are using arrow functions in passed in object properties.

Comment: I feel silly now because I didn't test the code, the one time I don't, something messes up